# C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

I need to print `num` after `num(num-1)` until zero
have to do it in recursion style.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("what is num?");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        downnums(num);
    }

    public static void downnums(int num)
    {
        if (num == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("that all");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(downnums(num-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: `downnums` doesn't return anything, so you can't use its result as an argument for `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: “It was a queer, sultry summer, the summer they executed the Rosenbergs".

Comment: @BJMyers, why not post it as answer?

Comment: @Rahul Because that would block the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from deleting the question.

Comment: @BJMyers, yep ... got it. along the line ...

Comment: so how am i supposed to 2 that? @BJ Myers

Comment: change your method to return `int` instead of `void`

Comment: @LiadRosenberg I would recommend finding a C# tutorial or some other resource.  This is really basic stuff - you should learn why your code doesn't work so that you can fix it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember: `void` means your method doesn't return a value, so it cannot be assigned to other variable or passed to method as an argument like `WriteLine` method:

this is what you're looking for:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("what is num?");
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        downnums(num);
    }

    public static void downnums(int num)
    {
        if (num == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("that all");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            downnums(num-1);
        }

       }

    }
```